# Should I be worried about having too many levels of vectors in vectors?

Tags: c++

Should I be worried about having too many levels of vectors in vectors?
For example, I have a hierarchy of 5 levels and I have this kind of code
all over my project:

```
rawSheets[pos.a].countries[pos.b].cities[pos.c].blocks[pos.d]
```

where each element is a vector. The whole thing is a vector of vectors of vectors ...
Using this still should be lot faster than copying the object like this:

```
Block b = rawSheets[pos.a].countries[pos.b].cities[pos.c].blocks[pos.d];
// use b
```

The second approach is much nicer, but slower I guess.

Please give me any suggestion if I should worry about performance issues related to this,
or else...

Thanks

Comment: You should probably worry, but not about performance.

Comment: You might want to consider making a more general mapping between `pos` and a position, particularly if your structure is sparse.  For example, an `unordered_map` might be useful here.

Comment: @delnan I think when you say something you should state the reason behind it.

Comment: I won't go into detail as to why you should not worry about performance as my reasons for saying that don't really address your question and I'd probably end up ranting incoherently. What I'm saying is, this data structure looks unnecessarily complicated, lacking appropriate abstractions, which may impact maintainability and flexibility of the program.

Comment: @delnan OK and you suggest?

Comment: I suggest you focus on a better data representation instead of chasing vague feelings of performance issues. I had hoped that was clear.

Comment: @delnan is it so hard to be concrete? Better in what terms. Suggest, say something concrete. What happens if everyone comes in and writes you should write better representation. Be SPECIFIC.

Comment: I probably would make a function to return the `blocks[]` element for `pos` object, like... `Block &b = get_block(pos);` wont make it faster, but more readable.

Comment: @user2381422:  If you can write up an appropriate hashing function for `pos`, then you could flatten this entire structure into an `unordered_map`.  The advantage of such a structure is that it only requires one level of indirection, not 5, and allows you to easily say `Block &b = umap[pos];`.  The downside, of course, is that you cannot refer to supersections (such as an entire city).  It all depends on if your operations are all at the block level, or at different levels.

Comment: Yes, it's indeed really hard to be specific without details on what you're trying to do, what data you have and how you use it. Perhaps encapsulate `pos` and that five-level data structure, and provide a member function to get the `Block` for a given `pos`. Perhaps it's worth introducing intermediate objects (`Country`, `City`, etc.) so you don't have a five-dimensional vector but a bunch of meaningful objects which can be reasoned about in isolation.

Comment: @delnan there you go, that was much better. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efficiency won't really be affected in your code (the cost of a vector random access is basically nothing), what you should be concerned with is the abuse of the vector data structure.

There's little reason that you should be using a vector over a class for something as complex as this. Classes with properly defined interfaces won't make your code any more efficient, but it WILL make maintenance much easier in future.

Your current solution can also run into undefined behaviour. Take for example the code you posted:

```
Block b = rawSheets[pos.a].countries[pos.b].cities[pos.c].blocks[pos.d];
```

Now what happens if the vector indexes referred to by `pos.a`, `pos.b`, `pos.c`, `pos.d` don't exist in one of those vectors? You'll go into undefined behaviour and your application will probably segfault (if you're lucky).

To fix that, you'll need to compare the size of ALL vectors before trying to retrieve the `Block` object.

e.g.

```
Block b;
if ((pos.a < rawSheets.size()) && 
    (pos.b < rawSheets[pos.a].countries.size()) &&
    (pos.c < rawSheets[pos.a].countries[pos.b].cities.size()) &&
    (pos.d < rawSheets[pos.a].countries[pos.b].cities[pos.c].blocks.size()))
{
    b = rawSheets[pos.a].countries[pos.b].cities[pos.c].blocks[pos.d];
}
```

Are you really going to do that every time you need a block?!!

You *could* do that, or you can, at the very least, wrap it up in a class...

Example:

```
class RawSheet
{
    Block & FindBlock(const Pos &pos);

    std::vector<Country> m_countries;
};

Block & RawSheet::FindBlock(const Pos &pos)
{
    if ((pos.b < m_countries.size()) &&
        (pos.c < m_countries[pos.b].cities.size()) &&
        (pos.d < m_countries[pos.b].cities[pos.c].blocks.size()))
    {
        return m_countries[pos.b].cities[pos.c].blocks[pos.d];
    }
    else
    {
        throw <some exception type here>;
    }
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
try
{
    Block &b = rawSheets[pos.a].FindBlock(pos);

    // Do stuff with b.
} 
catch (const <some exception type here>& ex)
{
    std::cout << "Unable to find block in sheet " << pos.a << std::endl;
}
```

At the very least, you can continue to use vectors inside the `RawSheet` class, but with it being inside a method, you can remove the vector abuse at a later date, without having to change any code elsewhere (see: [Law Of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter))!

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I should make the FindBlock function const?

Comment: Re: Out of range `pos.*` values: Just use `std::vector::at()` if you worry about this (many people don't, and they get by OK). Also, the law of demeter would apply to the `FindBlock` implementation too.

Comment: Checking the indices is not a problem, we have a strategy to always provide valid indices to keep these things fast and so checks are not needed. But I like the function, will implement it now.

Comment: @user2381422 It depends if you're going to be modifying the block that you get. If you make the FindBlock method const, you'll only get a const reference to the `Block` object back. If you want to make changes to the Block object, you'll need to leave it non-const.

Comment: By the way, isn't this indirection going to be slower? I mean I will be calling a function to get the reference, rather than just use the vectors directly.

Comment: @user2381422 It may introduce a very minor cost, but the method could also be inlined by the compiler, meaning that the overhead would be removed during compilation.

My advice to you would be not to worry about the cost of indirection at this point. In the words of the great Donald Knuth: "_[Premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize)_"

Comment: @delnan Yeah the implementation of FindBlock as I described it is a violation of LoD too, but that can be altered in time if necessary. The key point I was trying to make was to remove the violation from any calling code in the first cut. The point of LoD is to hide implementation details to aid in maintenance and self-describing code. The calling code needs to find a `Block` inside the `RawSheet`, but it shouldn't care how it gets found.

Answer (score 1):

Use references instead. This doesn't copy an object but just makes an alias to make it more usable, so performance is not touched.

```
 Block& b = rawSheets[pos.a].countries[pos.b].cities[pos.c].blocks[pos.d];
```

(watch the ampersand). When you use b you will be working with the original vector.

But as @delnan notes you should be worried more about your code structure - I'm sure you could rewrite it in a more appropriate and maintable way.

Comment: Can you be more specific please? Not sure how to rewrite that, I really need to be able to access various levels in the hierarchy like that. By the way thank you for the reference advice, very nice!

Comment: I cannot really help you in sense of restructuring code until I know how does it work right now. But I guess that would be not as easy to do if you have already done it this way, so maybe stick with it. Just use references to make it more usable

Comment: Or just look at the @KarlNicoll answer if you want to make some changes

Answer (score -1):

You should be worried about specific answers since we don't know what the constraints are for your program or even what it does?

The code you've given isn't that bad given what little we know.

The first and second approaches you've shown are functionally identical.  Both by default will return an object reference but depending on assignment may result in a copy being made.  The second certainly will.

Sasha is right in that you probably want a reference rather than a copy of the object.  Depending on how you're using it you may want to make it const.

Since you're working with vectors, each call is fixed time and should be quite fast.  If you're really concerned, time the call and consider how often the call is made per second.

You should also consider the size of your dataset and think about if another data structure (database perhaps) would be more appropriate.